# Is it possible to customise column width of bar chart created using AmChart

Tags: html, css, amcharts

I am having issue with the AmChart column width that column names is overlapping to each other. See below image.
[image: Bar chart using amchart]

Please advise if possible to change column width or to bring extra content in next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply adding \n (New Line operator) now extra content is coming to next line

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [columns width](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#columnWidth) in your graph, but that doesn't define the space available for your labels.

Ideally you would be changing the [labelRotation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelRotation) in your `CategoryAxis`:

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "labelRotation": 45
}
```

Please check the example here: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/574ba080c90e5030bae9352a31465086